# Change language of custom button lightning component whenever language of the user is changed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel, translation

I have a LC quick action i need to change the label of the component or i can say translate it to spanish language according to users language. In workbench am unable to see the component to  translate how can i achieve it through in LC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood your issue, but if what you pretend is to translate a Quick Action Label you can do that through Translation Workbench, selecting *Action* on the Setup Component. Below is an example:

[image]